# how to insert multiple columns in a single column of another table in sql

Tags: postgresql, unpivot

I have the following table:

[image]

Then I want to get the following:

[image]

I want to achieve this in postgres. What should I do?

Comment: how can I make this a generic one which would apply to any tables

Comment: You can create procedure to perform this action automatically. In that procedure You'll obtain all the names of tables in Your database and the field(s) in their primary indexes from INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabular data can be easily **unpivoted** with the help of JSON functions.

The query below will work, assuming `tablename` is replaced by your table name, and `primary_key` is the name of the pivot column. The other columns don't have to be specified, they're obtained automatically by `json_each_text` applied to `row_to_json` applied to all rows.

```
SELECT primary_key, key, value
 FROM (select row_to_json(t.*) AS line, primary_key
     FROM tablename AS t) AS r
   JOIN LATERAL json_each_text(r.line)
     ON (key <> 'primary_key')
```